# get the value in div when button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When i click on the button i want to get the value inside div in MVC.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
        <div class="itemTitleHeader">
            @item.Title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="float:left; width:50%;">
            <div>
                <img src="@item.ProdImage" height="500" width="600" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; width:50%;">
            @*<div class="itemByDesc">
                @item.Itemby
            </div>*@
            <br />
            <div class="itemPriceDesc" style="">
                Price @item.ItemPrice
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="itemStatus">
                @item.ItemStatus
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @item.GetitBy
            </div>

            <br />
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Amazon", FormMethod.Post))
            { 
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
        <div>
            <div>
                @item.ProdDesc
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

so when i click on submit button i want to pass the value of @item.ItemPrice to controller. How to do that? I am trying to learn mvc. Might be silly question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may keep that value inside your form in a hidden field

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Amazon", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <input type="hidden" name="itemPrice" value="@item.ItemPrice" />
    <div style="float:right;">
      <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

Now make sure your `Details` action method has a parameter to accept this form value when the form is being submitted. **The parameter name should be same as your form field name.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(decimal itemPrice)
{
  // to do : return something
}
```